# Check if Advanced Compression is available

Tags: sql, oracle, compression

I'm searching a way to safely determine if a given Oracle Database has Advanced Compression available.

Based on this information I want to enable Basic Compression or Advanced Compression for certain tables.

I tried querying v$version, which seems a bit awkward but works for identifying if an EE is installed. But so far I didn't find a way to see if Advanced Compression is available.

```sql
--0 => No EE
SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM v$version
  WHERE banner LIKE 'Oracle%Enterprise%';
```

Is there a way to determine if Advanced Compression is available?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way. Available and "is licensed" are two different topics. And Oracle's licensing policy is really nasty play.

Comment: I am not sure but can you please check in view `wri$_dbu_feature_metadata`.
Advanced Compression needs licensing, and I am not sure about how licensed features are maintained. But you should give a try to the above view.

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to contain anything about advanced compression. I see Advanced Index Compression, but as far as I understand this only shows that it has been used.

Comment: @APC that seems to be a good candidate. It shows advanced Compression with a value of true or false.

Comment: I tested the V$OPTION suggestion on different databases and this seems to be working. I will happily accept this as an answer.

Comment: Be aware that v$option shows you what is *capable* of being used. That is not necessarily an entitlement to use it. In particular, Advanced Compression is a separate license on top of Enterprise Edition. Make sure you have that license before using it (the database will *not* stop you from using it if you are not licensed for it)

Comment: So any Enterprise Edition will have the Advanced Compression in v$option with a value of True? That would be bad

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about software licenses are off topic. Even if you get Oracle product managers answering the question :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to talk to your Oracle Account Manager and/or read the fine print on your Oracle License Agreements and Contracts.

The software generally ships with all features available to use. Features are accessible based on what you paid for.

If you don't know, assume you shouldn't use it.

Comment: That's unfortunate. So basically relying on basic compression if it is an Enterprise Edition is my best guess. Enabling Advanced Compression only if I have a "written" proof.

Comment: same with partitioning...you should only be using something if you paid for it

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - how about the `with … options` clause that comes up when we connect in sqlcl or sql\*plus? Can we rely on that or is it misleading too? (I'm a bit rusty on this as I have spent the last six years working at enterprises that just bought *everything*. Back in the real world now.)

Comment: I sometimes use Databases which are provided by the customer. So having a way to check for licensed features would be nice. But I understand that this is not possible.

Comment: @APC - you can trust that the feature is installed and available but not licensed

Comment: I suspect this is why we get so many answers here suggesting people use Partitioning without reminding them to check whether they have licensed it. Because people see `with Partitioning …` every time they connect to the database and think that means they're allowed to use it. I know Oracle employees grow weary of defending Oracle's licensing practices but this is an unsatisfactory state of affairs. Probably most developers have no idea who their Oracle account manager is, nor have every seen the contract.

Comment: @APC developers should be using the features the DBAs have delivered to them, it is possible to neuter said features in the database, for example not granting access to the diagnostic pack or turning off partitioning https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ntdbi/enabling-and-disabling-database-options-after-installation.html#GUID-C45D75FC-34B5-4C24-9DE8-1518044A3BB3

Comment: Shame `chopt` only supports a subset of the licensed Options. For instance even if a conscientious DBA had run that tool it would not have helped our friend here with Advanced Compression.

Comment: @APC agreed although licensing is a subject I try to stay out of, i stepped in here because I would hate for a customer to get into a bad spot based on bad, even if somewhat logical, assumptions